# network connection failed in Red 5 server

Tags: java, php, html, media, red5

I am new to red5 server. When i am trying to run red5 by creating a project in eclipse using red 5 plugin it runs with error. But when i am trying to run the client it shows unsuccessfull connetion. Please help me in this matter.

I am also getting this error when running therever 
"[INFO] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope default1 not found on localhost"

Please help me sir
Nick

Comment: I think this belongs to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to a scope "default1" which is not available in Red5.
Maybe you try to connect to one of the pre-installed webapps in Red5.
Or have a look at the sample applications, for example the oflaDemo is a good example to start with.